# Issues in birt deployment in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, birt

As per documentation available over link http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-setup.php
Have tried all steps but on copying WebViewerExample folder in webapps folder of tomcat server, the manager shows WebViewerExample as in false state. On copying entire birt-runtime folder the tomcat manager finally shows birt-runtime as true state. On clicking that however it is not showing expected page.
[Showing these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1OSp.png)

By changing url as follows 
localhost:8080/birt-runtime/birtViewer it is showing expected result.
However on clicking view example it is throwing 404 error.
Have tried possible options to solve this but it is not helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Birt did not properly sign their file properly. You need to go and delete 2 files in two locations to resolve this. Unfortunately the BIRT team has been aware of this problem for a long time, but having BIRT run on anything but Eclipse apparently isn't important to them.

You can find the details of the fix at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497356

And note that most (all?) of the people who didn't get it working - their mistake was they only deleted the 2 files in 1  place, when they deleted them in both places everything is fine.

HTH

Comment: Yes this is working as expected. You are right we need to delete the files from two locations as suggested in blog.